# How to get count of Frequency of All Unique Character Values in Data Frame

Tags: r, compiler-errors

```
customers %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(state.of.res, count(as.factor(state.of.res), wt = NULL, sort = TRUE, name = "Observations")))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = state.of.res)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  labs(y = "Count ->", x = "State of Residence ->")
```

How to use reorder and count correctly?

I was trying to get a bar plot of state.of.res in y axis and the frequency of each state in the x axis in a SORTED way.

Error:
Error in `geom_bar()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "factor"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

> 

Answer (score 1):

Use `count()` on the data before the `ggplot()` call.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Creating some data similar to yours
customers <- 
  tibble(id = 1:100,
         state.of.res = sample(state.name[1:25], 100, TRUE))

customers |> 
  count(state.of.res) |> 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(state.of.res, n), weight = n)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Count", x = "State of Residence")
```

[image]